# I can access a static fstream from one file only

Tags: c++, static, fstream, extern

I need to use a `static fstream` in multiple source files. However I can only use it from a single file and not from the others. Furthermore, its use in the other files does not give any error, it just does nothing.

This is the code:

```
/// log.h
#ifndef LOG_H
#define LOG_H
#include <fstream>
static std::ofstream ofs;
#define LOG(level) ofs << level << ": "
#endif

/// test.cpp
#include "log.h"
#include "other.h"
int main()
{
   ofs.open("file.log");
   LOG(5) << "Test log 1" << std::endl;      // OK
   OtherFunc();
}

/// other.h
#ifndef OTHER_H
#define OTHER_H
extern int OtherFunc();
#endif

/// other.cpp
#include "other.h"
#include "log.h"
int OtherFunc()
{
   LOG(5) << "Test log 2" << std::endl;      // Nothing
}
```

This is the generated file:

```
5: Test log 1
```

*Thank you!*

Platform:
Linux
g++ 4.5.1

Comment: You should consider making `LOG()` a plain old function.  Keep the state required (the stream in this case) somewhere private to the function's implementation. That way, you can avoid having everyone who uses it from having to know about the stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static` here means you're explicitly asking the compiler to give the file-scope variable `std::ofstream ofs` *static linkage*, which means it is visibly *only* in the current file.

The twist is that you're doing this in a header, which means every `.cpp` file including the header gets its own distinct instance of `std::ofstream ofs`. Only because you've given it static linkage can they all have distinct file-scope variables with the same name - otherwise there would be a name clash.

So, in `main.cpp`, you open your local `ofs` and write to it.
In `other.cpp`, you have your own local copy of `ofs`, but never open it ... so the output doesn't go anywhere, and certainly not to `file.log`.

---

The other answers are correct, that changing the header declaration to `extern std::ofstream ofs;` will allow all the `.cpp` files to share a single object called `ofs`, and then you just need to put the instance in exactly one place (`main.cpp` would be fine).

It might be simpler, and cleaner, to make the `LOG(level)` an out-of-line function call though; then the output stream could live in a `log.cpp` with the function definition, and nobody else *needs* to see it.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, you are right about using a .cpp file for the logger implementation, but mine is a particular case where I had to put everything in an include file.

Comment: @Pietro: if everything is in an include file, where is the single instance of `ofs`?

Answer (score 5):

Static global variables: variables declared as static at the top level of a source file (outside any function definitions) are only visible throughout that file ("file scope", also known as "internal linkage").
The default storage class for global variable is `extern` which has external or whole program linkage. So if you want to use the global variable in multiple files it must be `extern.`

Answer (score 4):

> I need to use a `static fstream` in multiple source files.

If you need to reference the same variable from multiple source files, that isn't `static` linkage, that is `extern` linkage.

Put this in your header:

```
extern std::ofstream ofs;
```

Put this in exactly one of your CPP files:

```
std::ofstream ofs;
```

Comment: You are right. I did it for OtherFunc(), and I forgot about the fstream. Thank you!